# Implementing a Firebase server-side countdown timer for Android?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, timer, server-side

Is there a way to implement a Firebase server-side countdown timer in Android Studio?

I want the timer to be server side, meaning that whenever a user opens my app the counter will always be at the same time for all users.

I read the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051212/firebase-countdown-timer-synched-across-multiple-clients) question, but they're 2+ years old and Firebase changed a lot since. It was acquired by Google in October 2014 and a significant number of new features were featured in May 2016 at Google I/O.

If Firebase can't provide that feature, is there another platform that can provide server-side countdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have better idea for countdown only calculate on clientside.

What happen if you do it:

1. Get Server Time in timestamp (add to `srvTime` variable)

Create new record for "countdown" timer:

1. Start time: `srvTime`
2. End time: `Time in ms when countdown ended` for example (5min = 60000*5)

And you can calculate in client side.

**Or** create a listener, for `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue()); 
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a server side timer that updates a value in your realtime database.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase('/firebase/database/url/time');
    new AnimationTimer(){
        start(){...}
        stop(){...}
        handle(){...ref.addValue(time);}
        };
```

That will update your real-time database every millisecond. To see it in your application just call it.

`Firebase ref = new Firebase('/firebase/database/url/time/value')`

```
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
            label.setText(ds.getValue() + "");
        });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError fe) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    });
```

It will update in real-time on your application in milliseconds. I was able to get this running in Java

Comment: This is my first answer on s.o. so please, let me know how I could improve my response.

Comment: Would you give an example on what format would you pass dates inside start () {...} and stop (){...} ?

Comment: Do note, as firestore charges you on number of reads and writes. Doing this with firestore will be a very costly idea.